# MySQL: Nearby locations for multiple latitude and longitude

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, location

I am creating a property search application using **Laravel 5.5 and MYSQL**. There user search for multiple locations for buying a property. The search result will show the property in the current location and it also fetches nearby location property for a better result.

If the user searches for a single location, I will get the latitude and longitude of that location and retrieve nearby location within 5KM radius using MYSQL query and show the property based on the locations.

But my issue is when the user search for 4 to 5 locations how to get the nearby locations for every location within a 5KM radius and sort the result based on distance. I searched a lot regarding this, but I can't get any resource

Here the database structure for location and Property table

**Location table**

- id *INT(10)*
- location_name *VARCHAR(255)*
- latitude  *DECIMAL(11,8)*
- longitude *DECIMAL(11,8)*
- active *TINYINT(1)*

**Property Table**

- id *INT(10)*
- property_name *VARCHAR(255)*
- location_id *INT(10)*
- active *TINYINT(1)*

Kindly help me in this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just repeat your query 4 - 5 times and combine results using "union" keyword in Mysql